# Stargazer and t-Statistics

Tags: r, stargazer

Does anyone know how to change to the format of t-stats in stargazer? I tried a bunch of things but haven't had any luck.

I would like the t-statistics shown below the coefficient and in brackets? i.e. drop the "t =" and replace with the t-statistic being shown in inside ( xxxx)

For example:

```
                  (1)

  Variable 1        0.102
                  t = 3.494
```

I would like

```
                 (1)
  Variable 1      0.102
                 (3.494)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in a non-`stargazer` option, you might want to try the [`modelsummary` package](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/) (disclaimer: I am the author). `modelsummary` accepts strings enclosed in curly braces in the [`glue` package format](https://glue.tidyverse.org/), so you can do a bunch of weird things. You can read the [details at this link](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#estimate-1), but here's an example:

```r
library(modelsummary)

models <- list(
  lm(hp ~ mpg, data = mtcars),
  lm(hp ~ mpg + drat, data = mtcars))

modelsummary(models,
  statistic = c(
    "statistic",
    "conf.int",
    "Std. Error: {std.error}{stars}"))
```

[image]

Comment: Cool. I think if you replace the last command with `modelsummary(models,
             output = "markdown",
             statistic = c("({statistic})"))`, then it addresses the question (modulo use of a different package).

Comment: Thanks! I misread the question, so I appreciate your correction. I edited the original post.

Answer (score 2):

There is no real option to do this with `stargazer` as the format of t-statistics is hard-coded.

Instead, replace the standard errors with the t-statistics and override p-values so the right stars appear.

I did this for multiple models below, as this is the more general solution (it works for one model too).

```r
library(stargazer)
#> 
#> Please cite as:
#>  Hlavac, Marek (2018). stargazer: Well-Formatted Regression and Summary Statistics Tables.
#>  R package version 5.2.2. https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=stargazer

models <- list()
models[[1]] <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp, data = mtcars)
models[[2]] <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + wt, data = mtcars)

get_ts <- function(fm) {
  summary(fm)$coefficients[,3]
}

get_pvals <- function(fm) {
  summary(fm)$coefficients[,4]
}

ts <- lapply(models, get_ts)
pvals <- lapply(models, get_pvals)

stargazer(models, type = "text", report=('vc*s'), se = ts, p = pvals)
#> 
#> =================================================================
#>                                  Dependent variable:             
#>                     ---------------------------------------------
#>                                          mpg                     
#>                              (1)                    (2)          
#> -----------------------------------------------------------------
#> cyl                        -1.587**              -1.785***       
#>                            (-2.230)               (-2.940)       
#>                                                                  
#> disp                       -0.021*                 0.007         
#>                            (-2.007)               (0.631)        
#>                                                                  
#> wt                                               -3.636***       
#>                                                   (-3.495)       
#>                                                                  
#> Constant                  34.661***              41.108***       
#>                            (13.609)               (14.462)       
#>                                                                  
#> -----------------------------------------------------------------
#> Observations                  32                     32          
#> R2                          0.760                  0.833         
#> Adjusted R2                 0.743                  0.815         
#> Residual Std. Error    3.055 (df = 29)        2.595 (df = 28)    
#> F Statistic         45.808*** (df = 2; 29) 46.424*** (df = 3; 28)
#> =================================================================
#> Note:                                 *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a minimal reproduciable example? I think there is no "t = " as default.

```
library(stargazer)
model <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp, data=mtcars)
stargazer(model, type="text")


===============================================
                        Dependent variable:    
                    ---------------------------
                                mpg            
-----------------------------------------------
cyl                          -1.587**          
                              (0.712)          

disp                          -0.021*          
                              (0.010)          

Constant                     34.661***         
                              (2.547)          

-----------------------------------------------
Observations                    32             
R2                             0.760           
Adjusted R2                    0.743           
Residual Std. Error       3.055 (df = 29)      
F Statistic           45.808*** (df = 2; 29)   
===============================================
Note:               *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Comment: Replace last line above with:    
    

    stargazer(model, type="text", report=('vct*'))